# SwiftUI architecture - value vs reference types

Tags: swiftui, architecture

Putting aside the reasons why one might choose a value type over a reference type, does SwiftUI itself prefer use of `@State` vs `@ObservedObject` in terms of architecture.

Here for example are two implementations of a basic list app - cats implemented using a `struct`, dogs using a `class`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Cat: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = "New cat"
}

final class Dog: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String = "New dog"
}

final class Dogs: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dogs: [Dog] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cats: [Cat] = []
    @ObservedObject private var dogs = Dogs()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Cats").bold()
            ForEach($cats, content: CatView.init)
            Button("New cat") {
                cats.append(Cat())
            }
            Divider().padding()
            Text("Dogs").bold()
            ForEach(dogs.dogs, content: DogView.init)
            Button("New dog") {
                dogs.dogs.append(Dog())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CatView: View {
    @Binding var cat: Cat
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $cat.name)
    }
}

struct DogView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dog: Dog
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $dog.name)
    }
}
```

Very little difference in terms of coding...so:

- Is there a reason why one might prefer one over the other? Apple's own examples often use structs + `@State` + `@Bindings`.
- Is there any performance implication for either choice, say when either Cat or Dog object has many fields (ObservedObjects let you precisely specify which attribute should generate an `objectWillChange` call), or if the arrays hold many items, i.e. 100k's?
- When would one go for a reference type, when Bindings give pseudo-reference attributes to a value type?

Comment: Generally, the preferred structure (as demonstrated in Apple's sample apps) is an ObservableObject with `@Published` properties at the top level that get passed down through child views. Note also, the important difference between `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject`

Comment: I think using reference types is more often used when the class contains more functionality, like containing dependencies that are themselves reference types. For example, having an observable object that contain an instance of CLLocationManager acts as the delegate for that object, then updating a published property when a delegate method is called. Otherwise, for simple data models, I think it's pretty much a matter of should I use a struct or class in general (besides SwiftUI), for which there are many articles and sources online to guide you.

Answer (score 2):

`struct`s are cheaper to create than `class`es since there is no cost of references or [ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Using structs also reduces the risk of shared-mutation bugs. See [Choosing Between Structures and Classes (Apple developer article)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes) on why to prefer `struct`s.

Your code also has a bug in it which you may not have initially noticed. Since `Dog` is a `class`, and `Dogs` contains an array of `Dog`, the `@Published` here won't help in certain scenarios. This is because `@Published` detects a value type changing, e.g. the array having different elements. However, this doesn't account for mutating a `Dog`'s `name` property. The `Dog` class reference in the array doesn't change so the `@Published` in `Dogs` doesn't emit an update. This is another bug caused by using a `class` instead of a `struct`. There is a way around this, but it introduces unnecessary complexity.

---

> Is there a reason why one might prefer one over the other? Apple's own examples often use structs + @State + @Bindings.

Prefer `struct`s because they are faster and less prone to bugs (see more detail above). In my apps I built / am building, I *very* rarely used `ObservableObject`s. They were the source of many bugs, unnecessary view updates, and complexity. The performance also greatly suffers when you have an `ObservableObject` with multiple `@Published` properties - changing one property updates *every* view which subscribes to the object updates.

> Is there any performance implication for either choice, say when either Cat or Dog object has many fields (ObservedObjects let you precisely specify which attribute should generate an objectWillChange call), or if the arrays hold many items, i.e. 100k's?

The cost here is mutating the **array** of `Cat` or `Dog`, so I doubt there would be a performance difference to prefer `class` over `struct`. As mentioned earlier, `struct`s are still more performant in general. Since in neither scenario the array is being *copied* (and if it was copied, it would again be the same) there is no difference.

> When would one go for a reference type, when Bindings give pseudo-reference attributes to a value type?

Use `ObservableObject`s when you rely on sharing data across a section of your app and potentially need some logic to get/set the `@Published` properties within. I (personally) only ever use `ObservableObject`s when I need to pass the object through the environment at some point with `@EnvironmentObject`.

---

To finish off, choose what **you** think is best for your architecture. Prefer `struct`s everywhere possible, and switch to `class` if it solves a problem that is too complex to solve just with `struct`s.